# expand Typescript definition for window object

Tags: typescript

I am working with Angular and Meteor using Typescript.
When I set up a collection I normally declare a global variable (that's the why meteor does it):

```
Invoices = new Mongo.Collection( 'invoices' );
```

Now I want to add the `Invoices` to my typescript custom definition so that code's intellisense doesn't trip over it.
However, `Invoices` is part of window object and I can't duplicate a module declaration.

Just adding this to my custom.d.ts file works for intellisense in my code

```
var Invoices: Mongo.Collection<any>;
```

However code doesn't like the `var`. It says I need to use declare module.
However, I can't redeclare module Window.

So I am a bit at a loss how to do it in a correct way.

Comment: `declare var Invoices: Mongo.Collection<any>;` seems to work. Is that the best way?

Comment: Please, convert this comment in an answer. It's the best one for TS 1.8+. In fact, I think this is the only one which works inside a module.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Zeeshan's answer, interfaces in TypeScript are self merging. One other way you can define this variable is to add it to the `Window` interface by using

```
interface Window{
    Invoices: Mongo.Collection<any>;
}
```

Which can then be used with

```
window.Invoices = /* your collection */;
```

One thing to note here is that `window` is required in the above example, where are using Zeeshan's proposal it is not. Which to use depends on your preference of how explicit you would like your code to be. I agree that using `declare var` can be more convenient, but it could also leave a developer searching for what scope that variable is defined.

I am simply proposing this as it could be a valuable alternative approach, depending on your preference of explicitness.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah go with `declare var Invoices: Mongo.Collection<any>;`

[Good Tutorial for More Understanding](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#classes-advanced-techniques)

Happy Helping!

Comment: Zeeshan, with your edits you made a mistake. Code is Visual Studio Code, so not code :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the interface name is Window (W -capital ) and in your declaration you need to define small window.

```
interface Window{
    Invoices: Mongo.Collection<any>;
}

// somewhere in class
private myvar = window.invoice
```

Comment: Does this need to be added to a type definition file? Like what's the best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that seems to work fine is:
`declare var Invoices: Mongo.Collection<any>;`